# How can I make a release build with Visual Web Developer 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build, visual-web-developer

In web developer express 2008 there was a Build option in the menu.

In web developer express 2010 it is not in the menu anymore, and under the Debug menu option I can only make a Debug build.

**What is the new way to make a build release in 2010?**

[alt text http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/1nnd8pm.png](http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/1nnd8pm.png)

Comment: Yeah, this is terrible.  :<  I had to resort to calling msbuild without Visual Studio's interfaces, but I dont' think that woudl work for the web developer thingy.

Answer (score 5):

Select "Tools" -> "Settings" -> "Expert Settings".
This will enable "Build" -> "Configuration Manager".

There will be more folks asking the same question (it took me some time to figure this out), let's make this public info.

Answer (score 1):

On the screen capture you posted, there is a "Configuration Manager" option on the menu.  Try looking there for release vs debug build settings, including the current/active configuration.